# Can I get file path from Swing to explorer

Tags: java, swing, file

I read 
[FileTreeDragSource](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/FileTreeDragSource.htm)

Can I get file path from Swing to explorer.
Not explorer -> Swing!!

Swing -> explorer
I wanna get path with explorer

Answer (score 1):

Java's DnD support does allow you to drag things out of a Java application into a native one, but I think that it's limited to text and only alows target components which will accept text, like the address bar in a browser.

If the explorer address bar does not accept text from a drag and drop, you could always add a menu option to your application to "Open in Explorer" which just launches a new Explorer process with the file path as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you. 
I can grasp the file of the origin of copy, but will it be impossible to grasp the file of the copy ?

Comment: I think perhaps I am misunderstanding your question. Are you trying to drag and drop a File object from a Java application, to an Explorer window and have it copied to that location? Or are you trying to copy the *path* of a file from Java to the Explorer window? If the former, this is not possible.

Comment: Yes  Java to the Explorer window.
Why not?

Answer (score 0):

Use this as your Transferable and you should be golden!

```
public class FileList extends Vector<File> implements Transferable {
        final static int FILE = 0;
        DataFlavor flavors[] = {DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor};
        public FileList(File file) {addElement(file);}
        public synchronized DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {return flavors;}
        public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
            return flavor.equals(flavors[FILE]);
        }
        public synchronized Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
            if (flavor.equals(flavors[FILE])) return this;
            else throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor);
        }
    }
```